# sql locking for batch updates

Tags: sql, transactions, locking, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and C#.

I'm inserting a batch of rows in SQL Server with a column **Status** set with value **P**.
Afterwards, I check how many rows already have the status **R** and if there are less than 20, I update the row to Status **R**.
While inserting and updating, more rows are getting added and updated all the time.

I've tried transactions and locking in multiple ways but still: at the moment that a new batch is activated, there are more than 20 rows with status **R** for a few milliseconds. After those few milliseconds it stabilizes back to 20.

Does anyone have an idea why at bursts the locking doesn't seem to work?
Sample code, reasons, whatever you can share on this subject can be useful!
Thanks!

Following is my stored proc:

```
      DECLARE @return BIT 
      SET @return = -1 
      DECLARE @previousValue INT 
      --insert the started orchestration 
      INSERT INTO torchestrationcontroller WITH (ROWLOCK)
                ([flowname],[orchestrationid],[status]) 
                VALUES      (@FlowName, @OrchestrationID, 'P') 

      --check settings 
      DECLARE @maxRunning INT 

      SELECT @maxRunning = maxinstances 
              FROM   torchestrationflows WITH (NOLOCK) 
              WHERE  [flowname] = @FlowName 

      --if running is 0, than you can pass, no limitation here                
       IF( @maxRunning = 0 ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @return = 1 

            UPDATE torchestrationcontroller WITH(ROWLOCK) 
                    SET    [status] = 'R' 
                    WHERE  [orchestrationid] = @OrchestrationID 
        END 
      ELSE 
        --  BEGIN 


RETRY: -- Label RETRY
BEGIN TRY
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1

        --else: check how many orchestrations are now running 
        --start lock table 
        DECLARE @currentRunning INT 

      SELECT @currentRunning = Count(*) 
              FROM   torchestrationcontroller WITH (TABLOCKX) --Use an exclusive lock that will be held until the end of the transaction on all data processed by the statement
              WHERE  [flowname] = @FlowName 
              AND [status] = 'R'                  
              --CASE

      IF( @currentRunning < @maxRunning ) 
        BEGIN 
            -- less orchestrations are running than allowed 
            SET @return = 1 

            UPDATE torchestrationcontroller WITH(TABLOCKX) 
            SET    [status] = 'R' 
            WHERE  [orchestrationid] = @OrchestrationID 
        END 
      ELSE 
        -- more or equal orchestrations are running than allowed 
        SET @return = 0 

      --end lock table 
      SELECT @Return 

COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
--PRINT 'Rollback Transaction'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205 -- Deadlock Error Number
BEGIN

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.05' -- Wait for 5 ms
    GOTO RETRY -- Go to Label RETRY
END
END CATCH
```

Comment: Obviously if two threads read the count at the same time, and then go on to update, the number of rows can exceed 20.  Some example code would help diagnose the exact situation.

Comment: I've added my code, hopefully you can help more with that. I thought the problem was like you said but is there a way to solve that?
I thought the ISOLATION LEVEL might help with that.

Comment: The free pass for maxRunning = 0 seems fishy... 50 threads might read that, and then update 50 rows

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix it by setting the isolation level serializable + transaction on the tree stored procedures (two of which I didn't mention because I didn't think they were of importance to this problem). Apparently it was the combination of multiple stored procs that were interfering with each other.

If you know a better way to fix it that could give me a better performance, please let me know!